# Easier AMPscript for inserting order form data into data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm learning how to build a custom CloudPage form. I have an order form that needs to push the order to a DE. Currently, I'm using the format of:

`insertData("MyDE","EmailAddress", @emailAddress,"FirstName", @FirstName,)`

But I have over 50 possible items to order. Is there a simpler, cleaner way to populate the `insertData` block without having to list all 50 item field names and their variable names?

Comment: you can structure it differently, but the listing of all attribute-value pairs will be necessary.

Comment: Can you give more context/examples of what you mean? For example, does your DE list out a field for every single product? Will this just fit into a single column? How is this set up and what end result do you need?